# Thread model for Async API implementation using Spring

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on the micro-service developed using Spring Boot . I have implemented following layers:

- Controller layer: Invoked when user sends API request
- Service layer: Processes the request. Either sends request to third-part service or sends request to database
- Repository layer: Used to interact with the
  database

.

Methods in all of above layers returns the CompletableFuture. I have following questions related to this setup:

1. Is it good practice to return Completable future from all methods across all layers?
2. Is it always recommended to use @Async annotation when using CompletableFuture? what happens when I use default fork-join pool to process the requests?
3. How can I configure the threads for above methods? Will it be a good idea to configure the thread pool per layer? what are other configurations I can consider here?
4. Which metrics I should focus while optimizing performance for this micro-service?

Answer (score 1):

If the work your application is doing can be done on the request thread without too much latency, I would recommend it. You can always move to an async model if you find that your web server is running out of worker threads.

The @Async annotation is basically helping with scheduling. If you can, use it - it can keep the code free of the references to the thread pool on which the work will be scheduled. As for what thread actually does your async work, that's really up to you. If you can, use your own pool. That will make sure you can add instrumentation and expose configuration options that you may need once your service is running.

Technically you will have two pools in play. One that Spring will use to consume the result of your future, and another that you will use to do the async work. If I recall correctly, Spring Boot will configure its pool if you don't already have one, and will log a warning if you didn't explicitly configure one. As for your worker threads, start simple. Consider using Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Regarding which metrics to monitor, start first by choosing how you will monitor. Using something like Spring Sleuth coupled with Spring Actuator will give you a lot of information out of the box. There are a lot of services that can collect all the metrics actuator generates into time-based databases that you can then use to analyze performance and get some ideas on what to tweak.

One final recommendation is that Spring's Web Flux is designed from the start to be async. It has a learning curve for sure since reactive code is very different from the usual MVC stuff. However, that framework is also thinking about all the questions you are asking so it might be better suited for your application, specially if you want to make everything async by default.

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts.